# How to iterate over edit text fields in matlab GUI?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

In my GUI I have quite some edit fields with the names edit1, edit2, ..., editn. I try to access them in a loop.

I tried following:

```
for i=1:n
   pos = sprintf('edit%', i);
   content = get(handles.(pos), 'String');
```

with the following error message:

```
Reference to non-existent field 'pos'
```

Ideas? Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
pos = sprintf('edit%', i)
```

to

```
pos = sprintf('edit%d', i)
```

That specifies `i` should be formatted as an integer when building the string.